# Another generalization of open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, open-problem

Let $T: E \to F$ be a linear continuous function between Banach spaces. Let
$$
B_E (x, 1) := \{z\in E \mid |z-x| <1\} \quad \text{and} \quad B_F (y, 1) := \{z\in F \mid |z-y| <1\} \quad \forall x \in E, \forall y \in F.
$$

Previously, I proved that

> [Open Mapping Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522689/a-generalization-of-open-mapping-theorem) The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $T$ is surjective.
> - There is $r>0$ such that $B_F (Tx, r) \subseteq T [B_E (x, 1)]$ for all $x \in E$.
> - There is $r>0$ such that $B_F (Tx, r) \subseteq \overline{T [B_E (x, 1)]}$ for all $x \in E$.

Now I want to generalize above OMT a little bit, i.e.,

> **Corollary:** The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $T$ is surjective.
> - There is $r>0$ such that $B_F (Tx, r r') \subseteq T [B_E (x, r')]$ for all $x \in E$ and for all $r'>0$.
> - There is $r>0$ such that $B_F (Tx, rr') \subseteq \overline{T [B_E (x, r')]}$ for all $x \in E$ and for all $r'>0$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** Assume $T$ is surjective.

- By MPT, there is $r>0$ such that $B_F (T \frac{x}{r'}, r) \subseteq T [B_E (\frac{x}{r'}, 1)]$ for all $x \in E$. Equivalently,
  $$
  T \frac{x}{r'} + B_F (0, r) \subset T \left [ \frac{x}{r'} + B(0, 1) \right ].
  $$
  It follows that
  $$
  T x + B_F (0, rr') \subset T \left [ x + B(0, r') \right ].
  $$
  The claim then follows.
- By MPT, there is $r>0$ such that $B_F (T \frac{x}{r'}, r) \subseteq \overline{T [B_E (\frac{x}{r'}, 1)]}$ for all $x \in E$. Equivalently,
  $$
  T \frac{x}{r'} + B_F (0, r) \subset \overline{T \left [ \frac{x}{r'} + B(0, 1) \right ]}.
  $$
  Notice that $\alpha \overline A = \overline{\alpha A}$, so
  $$
  T x + B_F (0, rr') \subset \overline{T \left [ x + B(0, r') \right ]}.
  $$
  The claim then follows.